# Monopoly Cheaters Edition “roadblock”

Tags: monopoly-cheaters-edition

In the board game Monopoly Cheaters Edition, there’s a chance card that says roadblock. This allows for a player to put that card on a property of their choice and if someone reaches that property, they must stop and pay the rent.

My question is what happens if a player lands directly on that property? Would they pay just once or double the rent?

Comment: Why would one consider them paying double rent? If the player landed directly on it, clearly they weren't roadblocked. The real question is, does that player roll, hit the road block trying to leave, and then pay rent the second time? To which I suspect the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the road block does nothing as the player in question is not moving past the property so it has no impact. I will walk through two different situations to help explain the rules. They would owe you rent a single time just as if there was no card forcing a plyer to stop there.

Situation 1 what you have here. Player rolls the dice and ends their movement on the property in question and owe rent for landing on it. This is treated as normal if they had landed on it without a roadblock.

Situation 2 when a player rolls but should stop a few squares later. Once they hit the road block card they are forced to stop and pay rent to the owner as if they had landed on that card for normal means. Once they stop their turn is over as normal unless they rolled doubles and can roll again.

what the road block card is doing is ensuring that players stop on that property and pay rent to the owner but it does not earn the owner more rent if they would have stopped at it normally.